# My first 3D print, will my setting work?

Tags: pla, infill, layer-height

I'm planning to print using a public 3D printer (Ultimaker 3) and was wondering if my settings will work. There is a 4 hour time limit. The parts don't need to be strong.

I've provided some screenshots of the model I'm planning to print and of the settings I'm planning to use. Dimensions of the print are 61.1 x 75.0 x 50.0 mm. Filament is PLA. Also if there is still something I can do to speed up the print, I'm happy to hear your suggestions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the "combing" option, this may prevent some excessive retracts per layer, reducing the print time.

You should add some infill percentage to give the walls stability and provide a base for the top. It is difficult to see if the holes run through the whole object. If so, you definitely need some infill. PLA usually doesn't need a brim (blue lines on the bed around the print parts, option "adhesion"), but it will not be a problem if you use it.

Having an Ultimaker 3E I usually print one object at a time. The more objects on the plate the higher the change that something happens causing you to loose all your prints. You could print one object first to test it out (limited time) adjust and print the others later.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up just printing one of the larger walls as a test. The print seemed to be going fine at first but after it had finished about 2.5cm of the vertical wall something went wrong (here is a picture [link](https://ibb.co/9wJPRRT)). From what I found online it seems that the nozzle could have clogged up? Or do you find it more likely that the print failed due to my settings? I'm going to have another go today with different setting anyway.

Comment: The issue that caused my print to fail was the filament spool getting stuck.

Comment: @Pajunen I was about to mention that it looked like either a clog or a filament entanglement.